# publicRuntimeConfig in next.config.js is always undefined in prod/staging

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, openshift, next.js

I am deploying a node project that uses next.js to openshift where I set the environment variable MY_ENV. I have added the `publicRuntimeConfig` configuration to next.config.js to access it client side. It works in my local but when its containerized and deployed `publicRuntimeConfig` is `undefined`.

Here is my configuration from next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: { // Will be available on both server and client
      isProd: process.env.MY_ENV ? process.env.MY_ENV.includes('prod'): false,
      isStaging: process.env.MY_ENV ? process.env.MY_ENV.includes('staging') : false
    },
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    const eslintRule = {
      test: /\.js$/,
      enforce: 'pre',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      options: {
        emitWarning: dev,
      },
    };
    const cssRule = {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: false,
          minimize: true,
        },
      },
    };

    config.node = {
      fs: 'empty'
    };

    config.module.rules.push(eslintRule);
    config.module.rules.push(cssRule);
    return config;
  }
};
```

This is how I am trying to get the publicRuntimeConfig on my pages.

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

console.log(publicRuntimeConfig.isProd); //publicRuntimeConfig is undefined here.
```

Any help is appreciated.

> **UPDATE/FIX**

`publicRuntimeConfig` was undefined in higher environments because it was not part of the package that was getting deployed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does `undefined Error` occur in pages?

what about try to `getConfig` from `next/config` ?

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const getNodeEnv = () => {
  const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

  const isProd = publicRuntimeConfig.isProd || false;
  const isStaging = publicRuntimeConfig. isStaging || false;

  return { isProd, isStaging }
};

const env = getNodeEnv()

console.log(env)
```

Comment: yes it happens on pages and i added to the question how I am using it. Not sure if there is a difference in how i am using it vs what you have here. for some reason if i set the env variable in my local it all works fine.

Comment: I can't find diffrence with you. Actually your code works well for me. I use `next build`  command defore deploy for production. After build I use `pm2 start` with my custom file server.js but just `next start` it works.

Comment: thats what i am confused about. i use the same and it build fine in my local. I am thinking that i might be missing the file in my higher env. Is there a difference between your answer and how I am getting the publicRuntimeConfig

Comment: please check and find difference from my git. https://github.com/kkangil/nextjs-mobx-boilerplate I'm using `pm2 ecosystem`. process.env variables are set from `ecosystem.config.js` and I separated the `getNodeEnv` function in `utils/env`.  Finally I use env called from `getNodeEnv` (pages/_error)

Comment: Thanks man. I think the part of the problem was  the file not being included in the package that was getting deployed into higher environment